# Unhandled Exception: type '_DropdownRouteResult<int>' is not a subtype of type 'int?' when returning value from Navigator.pop()

Tags: flutter, dart

In a `DropdownButtonFormField`, I have a list of standard `DropdownMenuItems` populated from a Provider and an "Add New" button which pushes a `MaterialRoute` containing a `Form`. When submitted, the form asynchronously inserts the new data to the db via the `Provider` and returns the db id in the call to `Navigator.pop()`.

The intended behaviour is that the pop() callback should set the value of the dropdown field to the returned int value, and the dropdown menu should be closed, with the updated value reflected.

In the code snippet below, I have two versions of this "Add New" `DropdownMenuItem`.  The "working" version performs as expected, but doesn't close the dropdown menu when pressed (also as expected, given that it's a button and not a normal dropdown element).

The "broken" version fails to push the new route, and throws

```
E/flutter (24895): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type '_DropdownRouteResult<int>' is not a subtype of type 'int?'
E/flutter (24895): #0      _TeaProducerFormFieldState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:teavault/screens/stash/teaform.dart:70:15)
E/flutter (24895): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1109:30)
E/flutter (24895): #2      _TeaProducerFormFieldState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:teavault/screens/stash/teaform.dart:69:13)
E/flutter (24895): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter (24895): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
```

L70 referred to here is `_selectedValue = value;`.  The behaviour occurs whether I use async/await or .then() syntax.

I can't tell whether this is due to a pre-emptive type check or a weird failure to wait for the Promise due to something I'm missing.

Relevant code is as follows:

```dart
class _TeaProducerFormFieldState extends State<TeaProducerFormField> {
  int? _selectedValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final teaProducers = Provider.of<TeaProducerCollectionModel>(context).items;
    final teaProducerListItems = teaProducers.map((producer) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
      value: producer.id,
      child: Text(producer.name),
    )).toList();

    final workingAddNewTeaProducerButton = DropdownMenuItem<int>(child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final int newValue = await Navigator.push(context, AddNewTeaProducerRoute());
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = newValue;
          });
        },
        child: Text('Add New Manufacturer')));

    final brokenAddNewTeaProducerButtion = DropdownMenuItem<int>(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, AddNewTeaProducerRoute()).then((value) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedValue = value;
            });
          });
        },
        value: 0,
        child: const Text('Add New Manufacturer'));

    return DropdownButtonFormField(
      value: _selectedValue,
      items: teaProducerListItems + [brokenAddNewTeaProducerButtion],
      // child: addNewTeaProducerButton)],
      onChanged: (_) {},
      hint: Text('Select a manufacturer'),
    );
  }

}
```

*EDIT:*
After modifying per @Axel's suggestion and pulling in the subtree content directly for clarity, I have the following, but still receive

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      LocalHistoryRoute.didPop (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart)
#1      _RouteEntry.handlePop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2896:16)
#2      NavigatorState._flushHistoryUpdates (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3868:22)
#3      NavigatorState.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4910:7)
#4      Navigator.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2432:27)
#5      _DropdownMenuItemButtonState._handleOnTap (package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart:148:15)
```

I thought to add an `int?` type arg to the relevant MaterialPageRoute, but received the same result.

```dart
final brokenAddNewTeaProducerButton = DropdownMenuItem<int>(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push<int?>(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                  Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                        title: Text('Define new Manufacturer'),
                      ),
                      body: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            flex: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 4 : 1,
                            child: Container(),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 16,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0),
                              child: const TeaProducerForm(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                  ))).then((value) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedValue = value;
            });
          });
        },
        value: 0,
        child: const Text('Add New Manufacturer'));

//[...]

class TeaProducerFormState extends State<TeaProducerForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String? fullName;
  String? shortName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            onSaved: ((value) {fullName = value;}),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter full name',
              labelText: 'Full Name'
            ),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            onSaved: ((value) {shortName = value;}),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter abbreviated name',
                labelText: 'Short Name'
            ),
            validator: ((value) {
              if ((value ?? '').length > 6 ) {
                return 'Please enter a name with six or fewer characters';
              } else if ((value ?? '').isEmpty ) {
                return 'Please enter a name with one or more characters';
              }
            }),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {

                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Saving new manufacturer...')),);
                  _formKey.currentState?.save();

                  final teaProducers = Provider.of<TeaProducerCollectionModel>(context, listen: false);
                  teaProducers.insert(TeaProducer(
                      name: fullName!,
                      shortName: shortName!
                  )).then((value) {
                    print('added tea as id $value');
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
                    Navigator.pop<int?>(context, value);
                  });
                }
            },
            child: const Text('Submit'))
          // Add TextFormFields and ElevatedButton here.
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specify the type you expect in return from `Navigator.push` and the type you want to return when you `Navigator.pop` inside of AddNewTeaProducerRoute.

Your code should look like:

```
final brokenAddNewTeaProducerButtion = DropdownMenuItem<int>(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push<int?>(context, AddNewTeaProducerRoute()).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedValue = value;
        });
      });
    },
    value: 0,
    child: const Text('Add New Manufacturer'));
```

And inside of AddNewTeaProducerRoute, do:

```
Navigator.pop<int?>(context, value);
```

You shouldn't get any cast exceptions after this.